# Rebus: Representing

Tags: rebus

I didn't write this rebus, either, but I'm still sharing it.

Image form:

[image: Image form of rebus]

Text form:

```
D  B1
N  B2
A  B3
T  B4
S  B5
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's go with

> Stand up and be counted

Comment: dang it! you beat me by 20 seconds!!!!

Comment: You'll get quite far going with that. Well, not too far, I guess, but all the way to the answer. All aboard the Correct Train. Choo choo!

Comment: Great, now I have "For Those About to Rock (We Salute You)" running through my head.

Comment: And that reminds me of "One does not simply rock into Mordor"